# Managed Assembly in C++ Solution via NuGet

Tags: c++, .net, nuget, managed

We need to use managed code in our native C++ solution. Until now the assemblies were copied manually to the project's root folder. 
After that it was necessary to execute *regasm.exe* which registered the assembly and created associated *tlb* file. We would like to automate this process with help of NuGet packages.
How is the correct way to achieve this?